# Using JCESecurityModule on Android device

Tags: android, encryption, jpos

While trying to carry out an encryption and decryption process on an Android environment, i have the below log.

> com.s.sdk.security.SMException: Error loading Local Master Keys, file:
>   "/cfg/lmktest.lmk" does not exist. Please specify a valid LMK file, or
>   rebuild a new one. 09-21 11:56:31.792 16182-16182/com.mpos.sdk
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.s.sdk.security.jceadapter.JCESecurityModule.init(JCESecurityModule.java:1785)
>   09-21 11:56:31.792 16182-16182/com.mpos.sdk W/System.err:     at
>   com.s.sdk.security.jceadapter.JCESecurityModule.(JCESecurityModule.java:159)

The reason why I will want to make use of JPOS is simply because I will want to carry out a financial transaction, which will be used in packaging my message.

For the encryption and decryption of data, I am to make use of this JCESecurityModule which works well on other platform, but not on the android OS.

**NOTE:** ***The file location in my android studio is app/cfg/test.lmk***

I was able to get this file from the **JPOS-master** on **github** found in the **jPOS-master\jPOS-master\jpos\src\test\resources\org\jpos\security**

i.e the ***lmk-test***

which was been used this way
 `JCESecurityModule sm = new JCESecurityModule("app/cfg/test.lmk")`;

I have also tried rebuilidng the lmk file, using the below method

```
public JCESecurityModule (String lmkFile) throws SMException
    {
        init(null, lmkFile, true);
    }
```

which can be found in the JCESecurityModule class (JPOS)
was still having same issue in loading the lmk file
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encryption was done by a device which is to be connected to a mobile phone to carrying out transactions, but the device makers actually did it this way to provide end to end encryption which you are circumventing. You don't need jpos in the device. You need it at your centrally deployed servers, where you would use real HSMs.

by **Victor Salaman**
in JPOS users google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jpos-users/X3r_PX7lgd4

but you can still carry out the encryption and decryption using some other Module instead of the JCESecurityModule (if the problem still persist). e.g. using the SunJCE

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, this was also asked on the jPOS's Google Group, and discussed there. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jpos-users/X3r_PX7lgd4

Comment: thanks...already gotten what i needed..thought of posting things been discussed in the group here...Thanks for sharing.